# UFW on Ubuntu to Allow All Traffic on LAN

Tags: ubuntu, ufw

I want to allow all LAN traffic to my Ubuntu server. I have read the documentation and see the command, but when I try to edit the command for my IP range I get an error. How can I allow all traffic starting at 192.168.15.0 - 192.168.15.255?

sudo ufw allow from 192.168.15.0/255
ERROR: Bad source address

It seems like the 15 (third octal) is causing the error. Almost like UFW does not expect a LAN to have a unique IP set.

Thank you

Comment: good question, but ufw is a simple interface above the iptables, you may able to do more control over packets via iptables. i prefer you to read this nice article about iptables: http://www.faqs.org/docs/iptables/

Comment: @pylover This is not helpful for this question. UFW is useful to simplifiy iptable tasks and what he wants to do is possible with it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.15.0/24
```

Comment: Yes. 192.168.15.0/24 includes adresses from 192.168.15.1 to 192.168.15.254.

Comment: For those wondering about the `/24`, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation). Essentially, the first 24 bits of the IP address (`192.168.15`) are fixed.

Comment: I might be nitpicky, but 192.168.15.0/24 is actually from 192.168.15.0 to 192.168.15.255, totaling 256 IPs as 2^(32-24)

Comment: For UDP, I had to create a separate rule: `sudo ufw allow proto udp from 192.168.15.0/24`

Answer (score 8):

you need to do sudo ufw allow from yourip/24 like this

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24
```

replace 1 with your ip router.

To allow connections for particular IP addresses ranging from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.254 to port 22 (SSH), run the following command

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 22
```